# How do I sign in to PlayStation Network on a second hand PS3?

Tags: ps3, psn

I bought a second-hand PS3, which still has the previous owner's old account on it. I have no way of knowing the last owner's info for PSN.

I've tried to sign in to my own account but can't. How do I remove the previous account so I can use my own?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a factory reset of the device? This would seem to be the easiest way to get rid of traces of any previous use.

Answer (score 1):

Factory reset is not really necessary. I've bought a second-hand PS3 too and just added my account next to that already exists.

Despite this, I suggest a factory reset of the console software and configuring it again.